# SUM where SUBSTR SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, substr

I have a problem with this two selects , I dont know how to use Sum with where and Substr 
Please help :)

This is assignment - /*Sum (THA01.MTDBC9)  where  substr (CETYK9, 1, 2) in ( '22', '23') and THA11.CDPAIS = 'SK' for card/ card r*/

My solution (Its wrong) - WHEN SUM (MTDBC9(CASE SUBSTR(CETYK9,1,2) in ('22','23') THEN CDPAIS = 'SK' AS V_TRX_VISA_NOTONUS

This is assignment - /*Sum (THA01.MTDBC9)  where  substr (CETYK9, 1, 2) in ( '24', '26')*/

My solution (Its wrong) - SUM (MTDBC9(CASE SUBSTR(CETYK9,1,2 in ('24','26')) AS V_TRX_VISA_INTER

What is the select with correct syntax ?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? Show the full query. What is the problem you're seeing? Error message? Incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

```
SELECT SUM(t1.MTDBC9) AS V_TRX_VISA_NOTONUS
  FROM THA01 t1
  INNER JOIN THA11 t2
    ON t2.something = t2.something
  WHERE SUBSTR(CETYK9, 1, 2) IN ('22', '23');
```

I can't fill in the join criteria between THA01 and THA11 as not enough information has been provided.

## 2

```
SELECT SUM(t1.MTDBC9)
  FROM THA01 t1
  WHERE SUBSTR(CETYK9, 1, 2) IN ('24', '25');
```

Share and enjoy.